# How can I access this in angular($window).bind()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to perfom an action when a user scrolls, however I am unable to access the scope of the controller.

My code is:

```
(function() {
    angular.module("myApp")
        .controller("MyController", ['$window', function($window){

            this.sidebarFixed = false;  

            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                console.log(this.sidebarFixed);
            });
    }]);
})();
```

The output of this is `undefined`. How can I access `this` inside the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of `this` inside the event handler is not the controller...it is `window` since that is what `$window` references

Try storing reference of controller `this` in variable and using that inside the event handler.

Your issue is  common problem using `this` in javascript so storing reference is always a good practice

```
(function() {
    angular.module("myApp")
        .controller("MyController", ['$window', function($window){
            var vm = this; // store reference then always use variable
            vm.sidebarFixed = false;  

            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
                // `this` is `window` here
                console.log(vm.sidebarFixed);
            });
    }]);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. However, when I change the value it isn't updated in the view. How can I fix that?

Comment: I injected $scope into my controller and called `$scope.$apply()` and it now updates the view, is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Because event occurs outside angular context if you update scope you need to notify angular to run a digest. In most cases can use `$apply()` but since scroll event can happen many many times a second might be best to use `$timeout`